# Help tidying up some jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have some javascript (jQuery) that i think is a little bloated and I was wondering whether or not there is a better way to code it, the code basically does the following the first class with the biography is shown, and the rest are hidden, a user then clicks and image, from that we get the index number and work out which `.biography` the image belongs to we then animate the old text out and the new in, below is what I believe to be quite messy code, and was wondering if there is a qiucker way to achieve what I am doing?

```
    $('.biography:first').show().addClass('visible');
            $('.biography:not(.visible)').css("top", "300px");
            $('.the-team img').click(function(){
                var clickedImage = $(this);
                $('.visible').animate({"top" : $('.the-team').height()+10 }, 1000).removeClass('visible').fadeOut(5);
                var indexToShow = clickedImage.index() + 1;
                if(indexToShow == 1) {
                    indexToShow = 2;
                } else if(indexToShow == 5) {
                    indexToShow = 4;
                } else if(indexToShow == 7) {
                    indexToShow = 5;
                }
                $('.biography:nth-child('+indexToShow+')').addClass('visible').show();
                $('.biography:nth-child('+indexToShow+')').animate({"top" : "123px"}, 1000);
            });
```

I have just been doing some x-browser testing, and apparently website broswers work out the indexes differently to moz based browsers, could anyone help on this?

Below is my HTML markup,

```
<article class="the-team">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if($post->ID == 15) : ?>
                <h1>your team</h1>
            <?php else: ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif;?>
        <section>
        <?php query_posts('post_type=team&order=ASC'); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <article class="biography">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile;  endif; ?>
        </section>
    </article>
```

Comment: If the code is readable and performs relatively well, then you can probably call it a day.  I think that smaller code will only serve to confuse anyone other than yourself.  Unless you're doing this as an exercise, of course.

Comment: This code looks perfectly fine. You could put more commands in one line but that wont really add any benifit. As of right now its perfectly readable and maintainable.  If you try and put too much logic in one line by reducing the amount of code you can also make it more cryptic looking and less maintainable.  The goal is to make it as human readable as possible.

Comment: What exactly does this do? if(indexToShow == 1) {
                    indexToShow = 2;
                } else if(indexToShow == 5) {
                    indexToShow = 4;
                } else if(indexToShow == 7) {
                    indexToShow = 5;
                }

Comment: @mplungjan that set of if statements allows me to target the correct .bio based on which has been clicked

Comment: Yes, but why the seemingly random selection of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the code seems fine. Only thing that I noticed:

```
$('.biography:nth-child('+indexToShow+')').addClass('visible').show();
$('.biography:nth-child('+indexToShow+')').animate({"top" : "123px"}, 1000);
```

could be changed to:

```
$('.biography:nth-child('+indexToShow+')').addClass('visible').show().animate({"top" : "123px"}, 1000);
```

This will save the time to find the nth child again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be done more efficiently. I suspect jQuery lint (or FireQuery if you are using FireBug) would give you some warnings about using the same selectors more than once, and using class-only selectors. It would be much easier for us to "optimise" if you posted your actual rendered HTML, or even better created a jsFiddle that we could work with.